# wrapping EWS API in WCF for silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, exchangewebservices

I am trying to read and send email from a Silverlight app integrated with Exchange server.

I gone through some forum and understood that I cannot use EWS directly through the Silverlight application. I have to use WCF and wrap the EWS API in it. I don't know how to do it. Can anyone tell me how to use EWS in WCF service?

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a large field - but depending on which capabilities you need you can do this very easily. There are some [videos here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) to get you started with WCF. You need to understand the WCF ABCs (address, binding, contracts) to write a robust solution.

As for Exchange integration - I suggest using the [EWS Managed API](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480) as a starting point. It provides a .NET wrapper over the lower level web services interface to Exchange. It will save you time as long as it has all the method interfaces you seek.